# Is it possible to interact with the DOM of a directory?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, browser, directory

When I navigate to a directory, e.g. `my-domain.com/directory_of_files/`, the directory is displayed in the browser, and I can inspect the elements in dev tools.  This mostly consists of `<a>` links embedded within `<table>`s.

Given that the site in question is my own, is it possible to interact with the DOM of a directory page and affect how it is rendered?  If so, how?  I've tried changing elements in dev tools, but I'm not sure how I'd do this from my own html/css/javascript.

Comment: That'll be generated by your web server. Which web server are you using?

Comment: @Alohci I'm using Firebase hosting, though I could also use Google Cloud Run.